# Twitter Library for ASP.NET MVC that implements REST API

Tags: asp.net, twitter

I been looking for a twitter lib for my ASP.NET NET MVC 3 software, but I need to implement the REST API functions that I nor found in Twitter Helper or Twitterizer. Rest API allow me to use a Find People query.

There is another one could solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to try looking into a library, such as TweetSharp that already has wrappers around a substantial amount of the Twitter API methods. If that doesn't work for you, consider writing your own wrapper around the methods you need using libraries such as HammockRest or RestSharp that have support for working with http, oauth and other such features that may assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking better in Twitterizer I found what I need, perform Search People, and other functions. I recommend [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net) to use twitter in ASP.NET MVC 3, ´cause the oAuth process has a better code.

Here the Sample code to peform Search People in twitter using Twitterizer :

```
                UserSearchOptions options = new UserSearchOptions();
                options.NumberPerPage = 40;
                options.Page = 1;

                TwitterResponse<TwitterUserCollection> usersResponse = TwitterUser.Search(tokens,pesquisa.Conteudo,options);

                if (usersResponse.Result == RequestResult.Success)
                        {

                          StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder();

                          foreach (var u in usersResponse.ResponseObject)
                          {

                              list2.Append(u.Name + "-" + u.Id);

                          }
                          ViewBag.Result_Twitter = list.ToString();
                        }
```